# get user profile large picture from facebook with omniauth in devise 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I want get the user profile large or normal picture from facebook. Now I get the square version from user profile picture with this code:

```
:image => access_token.info.image
# http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=square
```

How can I get the large or normal versions?

Or and the app, How can I replace in this url the last word, large instead square...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Below are the 4 Different Size of profile pictures that is allowed by facebook.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=small
http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=square
http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=large
http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=normal
```

Comment: Thank you but I know that this 4 different size of profile pictures. My question is that I receive square version from data facebook, and I want use in my rails app also other 3 versions. Thank you!

Comment: this tells you the sizes, but does not really solve the problem

Comment: change the url to reflect the different size.  you already have the photo id so you have everything you need

Answer (score 33):

If you want to grab a different size picture at login time, the omniauth-facebook strategy has an option to change which picture is requested.

> image_size: Set the size for the returned image url in the auth hash.

For example, the large picture would be requested in omniauth.rb this way:

```
provider :facebook, 'secrets', 'sekrets', :image_size => 'large'
```

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring

Comment: Thank you I have checked this fix for me in my devise.rb file but it does not works fine for me :(. I received square version. I am using devise 2.0 with omniauth-facebook (1.2.0) gem!

Comment: This IS the proper answer to this question! Upvote people! :)

Comment: Now if only this didn't break the content spoof workaround https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1429#issuecomment-44291712

Comment: This works pretty good by the end of April, 2017. Just make sure that you restart your application after you do any changes to the files inside your 'initializers' directory ;)

Answer (score 4):

When you save it into the DB you could do it like this `access_token.info.image.split("=")[0] << "=large"`

and just change large to whatever size you want.

Or you could have a helper method for displaying different sizes in your views.

```
def profile_photo(type="large")
  puts @user.image.split("=")[0] << "=#{type}"
end

profile_photo("small") #=> http://url?type=small

profile_photo("square") #=> http://url?type=square

profile_photo #=> http://url?type=large

profile_photo("normal")  #=> http://url?type=normal
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the config file i just added `+ "?type=large"` to the url.

`<%= image_tag current_user.image + "?type=large" %>`

so you can request different sizes of it at any time.

`<%= image_tag current_user.image + "?type=normal" %>`

`<%= image_tag current_user.image + "?type=small" %>`