# Configuring avatar image sizes using Omniauth Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

Right now I'm trying to save large images for a user's avatar using [Omniauth Facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) and [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). It appears that after the user is created only the smallest image size is saved. I did some research and came across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10935563/3046413) that said to pass `:image_size` as a parameter. Unfortunately it doesn't exactly say where it goes. I assumed that it went in my `devise.rb` file but did not work:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "SECRET_KEY", secure_image_url: true, image_size: "large"
end
```

Where exactly am I putting this to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Omniauth Gem, you should be able to set a custom image size by passing it as a parameter and providing width and height in omniauth.rb file like so:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :facebook, "APP_ID", "SECRET_KEY",
{
scope: 'email,public_profile,user_location,user_birthday,user_about_me',
image_size: {width: 400, height: 400},
info_fields: 'name,email'
}
end
```